# ng2-Chart background color not reflecting correct value

Tags: angular

I have an line chart using these options however the background is not changing the color and are all using the default color. Am I missing something?

```
public lineChartColors:Array<any> = [
  {
    borderColor: 'rgba(128,139,157,1)',
    pointBackgroundColor: 'rgba(148,159,177,1)',
    pointBorderColor: '#fff',
    pointHoverBackgroundColor: '#fff',
    pointHoverBorderColor: 'rgba(148,159,177,0.8)'
  },
  {
    borderColor: 'rgba(47,63,46,1)',
    pointBackgroundColor: 'rgba(77,83,96,1)',
    pointBorderColor: '#fff',
    pointHoverBackgroundColor: '#fff',
    pointHoverBorderColor: 'rgba(77,83,96,1)'
  },
  {
    borderColor: 'rgba(128,129,157,1)',
    pointBackgroundColor: 'rgba(148,159,177,1)',
    pointBorderColor: '#fff',
    pointHoverBackgroundColor: '#fff',
    pointHoverBorderColor: 'rgba(148,159,177,0.8)'
  }
];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The pointBackgroundColor and backgroundColor are two different options, if you add in the backgroundColor it should reflect as you want

```
public lineChartColors:Array<any> = [
  {
    pointBackgroundColor: 'rgba(//someColor)', //add this
    borderColor: 'rgba(128,139,157,1)',
    pointBorderColor: '#fff',
    pointHoverBackgroundColor: '#fff',
    pointHoverBorderColor: 'rgba(148,159,177,0.8)'
  }, ...
```

Answer (score 0):

In .html file

```
 <canvas baseChart width="400" height="400"
                [datasets]="lineChartData"
                [labels]="lineChartLabels"
                [options]="lineChartOptions"
                [colors]="lineChartColors"
                [legend]="lineChartLegend"
                [chartType]="lineChartType"
                (chartHover)="chartHovered($event)"
                (chartClick)="chartClicked($event)"></canvas>
```

In .ts file

```
   public lineChartColors: any[] = [
              { 
                backgroundColor:["#0277BD", "#FB6542"] 
              }];
```

[colors] attribute of ng2-charts will change the color with the specified color in the array.